# How to wait until image fits screen while scrolling and then scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an image that I can scale while scrolling but what I want to do is make the image big until it fills the screen and then scroll to the next section.
This is my current code:
jsfiddle.net/4vm6025e/1/

Comment: Please add code fragments that you would expect to have the requested result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.